# Check if one of multiple values exists in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I already tried this:

```
<?php
function checkForOrange($farben) {
     foreach($farben as $element) {
            if(in_array('orange',$element) || in_array('Orange',$element)) {
           return $so;
      }
      return false;
}
}
$so = checkForOrange($farben);
if (!empty($so)) { echo "nothing"; }
if (isset($so)) { echo "daa"; }
?>
```

but it always returns "daa" even if i check for sfefrsefdeas.
Can someone please give me a working code for this?

Comment: Try the check as if(!isset($so) rather then empty. Also in checkForOrange where is the definition of $so?

Comment: $so is always set, when you explicetly declare it as $so = checkForOrange. In other words - you already set the variable.

Comment: i tryed if (!isset($so)) { echo "daa"; } and removed if (!empty... but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function to check existence of value in multidimensional array.

Function return true or false, you can use it in general.

```
function search_in_array($value, $array) {
     if(in_array($value, $array)) {
          return true;
     }
     foreach($array as $item) {
          if(is_array($item) && search_in_array($value, $item))
               return true;
     }
   return false;
}
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57d3364419ebb0e87a21ee8b65b7d15517d74a2d)

--------- edit -----------
Based on your comment, and an example of an array

```
function check_in_array($value, $array, $key){
 foreach($array as $item){
  if($item[$key] == $value)
  return true;
  }
 return false;
}
```

And then call it like this `check_in_array('orange', $array, 'FacetValueName');` 
 
Or this 
 
`check_in_array('orange', $array, 'FacetValueName') && check_in_array('Orange', $array, 'FacetValueName') && check_in_array('dark orange', $array, 'FacetValueName')` 
 
 to check multiple values at once.

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/228d71e72ce188056132704a1886e60b04d01419)

Comment: Your function is unnecessary big and same way recursive

Comment: Perhaps, but not necessarily. I dont have the example of array he is searching in (how much multidimensional, structure), and no idea how he use this in the big picture (some function, or new behavior in some eshop?). So I decided to provide general answer.

Comment: Thanks but it's checking only for one value, i need to check for two or more values and if only one or all of them match (example: "orange" or "Orange" or "dark orange") then return true

Comment: Could you post the whole code in the sandbox please? I don't know what comes in the row if($item[$key] == $value) if there have to be multiple values

Comment: Here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d352ad67d6f05488d0481ce1e90568fa04b701da , look at the $so variable, and undrestand how to use this function to check multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I see it. Assuming you are comparing in_array to the foreached value, you are having a multidimensional array. So I basically created two 2d arrays. One called $farben1 and the second $farben2. In the first one key `'fruits' => 0=> 'Apple', 1=>'Orange', 2=>'Lemon';` while the second has `Melon` instead of orange. So it does not contains the word 'orange'.

If think you can just compare if the lowered value of $element is 'orange', so I assigned `strtolower()` to your array $element.

```
<?php
function checkForOrange(array $farben) {
     foreach($farben as $element) {
         $bool[] = in_array('orange', array_map('strtolower', $element));
     }
     return in_array(TRUE, $bool);
}

$farben1['animals'] = array('cat', 'Dog', 'Lion');
$farben1['fruits'] = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Lemon'); //contains
$farben1['flowers'] = array('Roses', 'violets');

echo !checkForOrange($farben1) ? 'nothing' : 'daaa'; // prints daaa

echo "<br /> <br />";

$farben2['animals'] = array('cat', 'Dog', 'Lion');
$farben2['fruits'] = array('Apple', 'Melon', 'Lemon'); //does not contain
$farben2['flowers'] = array('Roses', 'violets');

echo !checkForOrange($farben2) ? 'nothing' : 'daaa'; // prints Nothing

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function i made to check if value is exist in multi-dimension array.

```
function is_val_exists($needle, $haystack) {
     if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
          return true;
     }
     foreach($haystack as $element) {
          if(is_array($element) && is_val_exists($needle, $element))
               return true;
     }
   return false;
}
```

You can use it like:

```
is_val_exists('your_value', $your_array);
```

It will return true if your_value is exists in $your_array.